# Display markdown safely as HTML in Vue3

Tags: vue.js, markdown, vuejs3, xss

So I have a set of strings, with some "custom markdown" that I have created. My intention is to render these strings as HTML in the frontend. Let's say, I have this string:

```
This is a string <color>that I need</color> to\nrender <caution>safely in the browser</caution>. This is some trailing text
```

I would be expecting to get something like:

```
This is a string <span class="primaryColor">that I need</span> to<br>render <div class="caution">safely in the browser</div>. This is some trailing text
```

And the way I do it right now is with some basic Regex:

```
toHtml = text
    .replace(/<color>(.*)<\/color>/gim, "<span class='primaryColor'>$1</span>")
    .replace(/\\n/g, "<br>")
    .replace(/<caution>(.*)<\/caution>/gims, "<div class='caution'>$1</div>")
```

This works fine and returns the correct string. And then for printing, in the template I just:

```
<div id="container" v-html="result"></div>
```

My problem is that at some point I expect users to be able to enter this strings themselves, and that would be displayed to other users too. So for sure, I am gonna be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Is there any alternative I can use to avoid this? I have been looking at https://github.com/Vannsl/vue-3-sanitize which looks like a good way of just allowing the `div`, `span` and `br` tags that I am using, and set the allowed attributes to be only `class` for all the tags. Would this be safe enough? Is there something else I should do?

In that case, I believe it will not be necessary to sanitize it in the backend too, right? Meaning, there will be no way for the web browser to execut malicious code, even if the string in the server contains `<script>malicious code</script>`, right?

Comment: I would (at most) suggest for looking for those that make you anxious. Look for those <script></script> tags and remove them in the backend while there are still no major processes happening in the backend (where you replace the strings and stuff).

Comment: But anyways they could just `<scr<script>ipt>something bad here</scr</script>ipt>` and that bypasses a simple check for `script` tag (unless I remove everything between it, which is also an option!). In the backend I am saving it as a string in a mongoose document btw (going through an ODM).

Comment: You could always just loop it again and again until the length of the string has not changed. That's a "slow" course of action for a Big-O Notation, but it is a good approach.

Comment: I re-read your comment. Yes, my point there was to yeet the whole tag and whatever is between them altogether, teach those guys a lesson or two.

Answer (score 0):

*My problem is that at some point I expect users to be able to enter this strings themselves*

So, Do we have a form input for the users to enter the string which you mentioned in the post ? If Yes, My suggestion is that you can sanitize the user input at first place before passing to the backend. So that in backend itself no malicious code should be stored.

Hence, By using [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method. You can first replace the malicious tags for ex. `<script>`, `<a`, etc. from the input string and then store that in a database.

Steps you can follow **:**

- Create a `blacklist` variable which will contain the regex of non-allowed characters/strings.
- By using string.replace(), replace all the occurrence of the characters available in the string as per the blacklist regex with the empty string.
- Store the sanitized string in database.

So that, You will not get worried about the string coming from backend and you can bind that via `v-html` without any harm.